# How to do not repaint JFrame? Just paint

Tags: java, frame, paintcomponent, mouselistener

I need help with simple program. I would like, when I click program marks it. I would like to see my moves did in past. Like pencil in paint.

class Test.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test{

    JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test smallTest = new Test();
        smallTest.letsDoIt();
    }

    public void letsDoIt(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton buttonOfTheEnd = new JButton("EXIT");
        buttonOfTheEnd.addActionListener(new theEndListener());

        graphPanel panelR = new graphPanel();
        panelR.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panelR);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, buttonOfTheEnd);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);


        frame.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

                frameMouseClicked(evt);

            }
        });

    }

    void frameMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {


        System.out.println("("+MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x+", "+MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y+")");
        frame.repaint();

    }

    class theEndListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent zdarzenie){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }


    // public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        // super.paintComponent(g);
        // int wspX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
        // int wspY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;

        // g.setColor(Color.RED);
        // g.fillRect( wspX, wspY, 10, 10);

    // 




}
```

class graphPanel

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class graphPanel extends JPanel{


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);


        int locX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x - 10;
        int locY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y - 30;
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillRect(locX, locY, 10, 10);
        }
}
```

thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Try to paint on an image in your `graphPanel` an paint the image to the component.
If you do not clear the image you attach every drawing.

```
class graphPanel extends JPanel{
    Image img;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(img == null) {
            img = new BufferedImage( getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR );
            img.getGraphics().setColor( getBackground() );
            img.getGraphics().fillRect( 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() );
        }
        int locX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x - 10;
        int locY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y - 30;
        Graphics imgG = img.getGraphics();
        imgG.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        imgG.fillRect(locX, locY, 10, 10);
        g.drawImage( img, 0, 0, this );
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Use `this` for the `ImageObserver`. 2) The component would not be resizable unless the image width & height was checked against component WxH in the `if(img == null)` check.

Answer (score 2):

You have to store the recent locations somewhere. A `List` is a good choice. Now, when you click somewhere on the screen, you add the location to the list and when you need to repaint the screen, you paint all stored location. That's something like *separating model and view* (the *model* is your list of 2D locations, the *view* is what you paint on the screen).

So create one list somewhere:

```
// public static only to keep it simple!!
public static List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
```

Then (thanks, oliholz!) add the listener to `panelR` instead of `frame`:

```
panelR.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  // ...
```

and write frameMouseClicked like:

```
void frameMouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
    points.add(evt.getPoint());
    frame.repaint();
}
```

Inside `paintComponent` you iterate through the list and draw all stored locations (again: very simple and reduced, improveable!)

```
g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
for (Point point:points) {   // <- this is the list of stored points
  g.fillRect(point.x, point.y, 10, 10);
}
```

Comment: use `points.add(evt.getPoint());` and add the `MouseListener` to `panelR`